# Почему по-разному удаляются папки в Windows-10?

Tags: windows, администрирование, windows-10

Есть ноутбук ACER Pentium четырехъядерный, довольно новый (CPU N3540 покупал два с половиной года назад). На нем стояла *Windows-8*, после покупки она проапгрейдилась до *Windows-10-64 Home Edition*. Windows-10-64 Home Edition периодически качает обновления.

В системе есть 4 диска:

- C:\ - системный
- D:\ - DVD-RW накопитель
- E:\ - съемный механический USB-3 винт от Трансенд 2 Терабайта
- F:\ - съемный механический USB-2 винт от Трансенд 1 Терабайт

Периодически я делаю бекап некой папки с диска `C:\` на диски `E:\` и `F:\` .
Папка довольно большая, порядка 60 гигов.
Бекап делаю тупо вручную, потому что это происходит довольно редко.
Перед бекапом я стираю старую копию папки с дисков E:\ и F:\ .

Так вот, проблема в том, что:

1. При стирании старой копии папки с диска E:\ старая копия падает в корзину.
2. При стирании старой копии папки с диска F:\ старая копия НЕ падает в корзину. Система заявляет, что папка слишком велика для помещения в корзину и желает ее удалить сразу.

При этом копии папки на дисках E:\ и F:\ ИДЕНТИЧНЫ.

Да, в обоих случаях корзину перед операцией удаления очищаю конечно же.

Вопрос:

1. Почему такое может быть, что с одного диска папка помещается в корзину, а с другого сообщает что такая же папка слишком велика для помещения в корзину?

*P.S.* Еще недавно, когда папка была поменьше, порядка 40 гигов, в обоих случаях система сообщала, что папка слишком велика для помещения в корзину.

Однако недавно, после установки очередного апдейта от Микрософт, поведение системы изменилось и с диска E:\ папка стала помещаться в корзину. Тогда как при удалении такой же папки с диска F:\ система по-прежнему сообщает, что папка слишком велика для помещения в корзину.

Comment: Ну и что беспокоит? Вы сами  еье ответили. Установили апдейт от Майкрософт - изменился алгоритм. Теперь (предполагаю) размер корзины не может быть больше 5% от ёмкости диска.

Comment: Действительно, похоже на то, что вместе с апдейтом изменились либо квоты на размер корзины, либо алгоритм помещения папки в корзину, либо и то и другое.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

у корзин на E:\ и F:\ разный объем
можешь:
 - удалить корзины на дисках
 - изменить их размер
 - удалять через Shift + Delete (безвозвратно, игнорируя корзину)

Comment: [у корзин на E:\ и F:\ разный объем] А почему тогда раньше в обоих случаях папка не помещалась в корзину? Ведь я не менял размеры корзин на дисках.

Comment: меня как раз это не беспокоит. большая папка не влезает, на этом все! показать как изменить размер корзины или удалить ее с диска?

Comment: Нет, показывать не надо, я уже и сам посмотрел. Размер корзины на диске E:\ 1.8 Тб. Размер корзины на диске F:\ 900 Гб. Даже размер меньшей корзины превышает размер удаляемой папки на порядок. Но почему-то система не желает помещать папку в корзину. Странно все это.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 нереальные размеры корзин! у тебя там точно не рейд на 20-100 Тб ?

Comment: [нереальные размеры корзин] Нереально большие или нереально маленькие? Нет, это точно не рейд на 100Тб. Это два переносных USBшных трансенда, которые лежат рядом с моим ноутом. Все размеры корзин назначила сама система, я сам ничего не исправлял.

Comment: Иногда бывает (не в этом правда случае), что система говорит, что длина путей и имен слишком большая, для помещения в корзину. Но тогда почему в одну корзину система может поместить папку, а в другую корзину не может? Странно все это.

Comment: Посмотрел повнимательней. Размер корзины на диске E:\ 97 Гб. Размер корзины на диске F:\ 49 Гб. Так что похоже, что все правильно. Скорее всего, что с очередным апдейтом микрософт изменила размер корзин. На одном диске удаляемая папка стала помещаться в корзину. А на втором диске как не помещалась, так и не помещается.